# How to display a property defined in build.properties file in ANT

Tags: ant

I have defined a property in my `build.properties` file, I am trying to check if the value is properly set or not using below code in my `build.xml` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<project name="myapp" default="showProps">
  <target name="showProps">
      <echo>My property is ${my_property.data}</echo>
      <echo message="${my_property.data}"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

But when I run the `ant` command I am getting output as:

```
showProps:
     [echo] My property is ${my_property.data}
     [echo] ${my_property.data}
```

Please tell me how to display the property value?

Answer (score 2):

Pass your properties file in the command-line:

```
ant -propertyfile build.properties
```

or load the properties file within the buildfile:

```
<project name="myapp" default="showProps">
   <property file="build.properties"/>
   <target name="showProps">
     <echo>My property is ${my_property.data}</echo>
     <echo message="${my_property.data}"/>
   </target>
</project>
```